# Cube Environment Map for Reflections OpengGl es 2.0 (Android/Java)

Tags: android, reflection, graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

i have read many tutorials about envoirement mapping for reflections, in some of them they are creating for every side of the cube one frame buffer in others they use one for the whole cube. Which is the right approach?

I am using java and Android 4.0.

I have follwing code and I am getting the glError 1282 on setting follwing:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + p_face, m_cubeMap[0], 0 );
```

The code for cube map generation is:

```
m_cubeMap = new int[1];
m_cubeFB  = new int[1];
m_cubeDB  = new int[1];
glGenTextures  ( 1, m_cubeMap, 0 );
glBindTexture  ( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, m_cubeMap[0] );

glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,     GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,     GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );      


glGenFramebuffers( 1, m_cubeFB, 0 );        
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_cubeFB[0] );

for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, m_cubeMapSize, m_cubeMapSize, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null );
}

glGenRenderbuffers   ( 1, m_cubeDB, 0 );
glBindRenderbuffer   ( GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_cubeDB[0] );
glRenderbufferStorage( GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, m_cubeMapSize, m_cubeMapSize );

glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,  GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_cubeFB[0] );
glFramebufferTexture2D   ( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, m_cubeMap[0], 0 );

glBindFramebuffer ( GL_FRAMEBUFFER,      0 );    
glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER,     0 );
glBindTexture     ( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0 );


if( LoggerConfig.ON )
    checkGlError( "InitRefCubeMap()" );
```

Before I iterate through all faces I set follwing state:

```
    glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_cubeFB[0] );
    glViewport( 0, 0, m_cubeMapSize, m_cubeMapSize );[/CODE]
```

For drawing every Face i, and where the Error will happen:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + p_face, m_cubeMap[0], 0 );       
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

if( LoggerConfig.ON )
        checkGlError( "DrawRefCubeMap() Face " + p_face );
```

****UPDATE****
Another device shows better debug information. On rendering I am getting following shader error:
06-18 17:58:53.093: V/ShaderHelper(11910): Log:Validate:  Sampler 'u_CubeMap' and 'u_ShadowMap' are of different types, but share texture unit 0.
But I am using different texture units for every different texture? If I remove all shadow map code, it will show the same error with another loaded texture.

****UPDATE 2****
I have validated the shader before all uniforms was set. After correting it the error is not apearing anymore.

Comment: By chance, when you were reading these tutorials, were you mixing them up with desktop OpenGL? You cannot attach layered images to a Framebuffer Object in OpenGL ES 2.0, you can only attach individual images (e.g. a cube map face or 1 slice of a 3D texture). Rendering into a layered framebuffer requires Geometry Shaders, and ES does not have those, so you have to do everything 1 layer at a time instead.

Comment: Also, cube maps are sampled using 3D texture coordinates... your wrap mode is only applying to `S` and `T` at the moment. There is also `R`, which defaults to `GL_REPEAT`. It is quite likely that you actually want `R` to have `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` as well.

Comment: Thanks for response. What do you mean by layered image? I am trying to write and draw to one side at a time.

I have tried to set the wrap mode, but the GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R is not available. I dont know why...

Comment: Layered images basically refer to textures with multiple images. A cubemap is one, 3D textures and array textures are other types. In ES 2.0, you can never attach a layered image directly and instead you always have to attach exactly 1 layer from the image. This was in response to your statement: *"in some of them they are creating for every side of the cube one frame buffer in **others they use one for the whole cube**"*. The only way to use one FBO for the whole cube requires attaching a layered image.

Comment: So I have to unbind the framebuffer object and texture of the cube and render to one layer per aktivating: glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + p_face, m_cubeMap[0], 0 ); ???

Comment: No, you do not have to unbind the FBO. But you do have to change the layer that is bound to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`, which is what `glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + p_face, m_cubeMap[0], 0 )` does (assuming `p_face` is **0**-**5**). You have to do that between each draw call when you want to draw into a different cube face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I am using the same fragment shader in cube map rendering and scene rendering. Even if the samplerCube was not used (by checking a uniform) in cube map rendering, it caused a crash in the fragment shader. By using another simpler fragment shader without a cubemap sampler it worked.

THe glError 1282 GL_INVALID_OPERATION indicates a missing frament shader.

Answer (score 0):

The `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error is most likely from the previous call:

```
glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
                           GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_cubeFB[0] );
```

The last argument you use is the name of a framebuffer, but must be the name of a renderbuffer. You need to change it to:

```
glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
                           GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_cubeDB[0] );
```

Once you narrow down a problem, it's generally a good idea to place `glGetError()` calls both before and after the suspected call, to confirm that the error was really triggered by that exact call.

Comment: But i am getting still the error if I am accessing the 3D Texture with following code in the fragment shader: 
`vec3 camRay  = normalize( ( u_CameraCenter - u_CubeCenter ) - ( v_WorldPos - u_CubeCenter ) );`

`vec3 wNormal = normalize( v_WorldNormal );` 
    
`vec3 reflection = textureCube( u_CubeMap, reflect( camRay, wNormal ) ).rgb;`

`vec3 refraction = textureCube( u_CubeMap, refract( camRay, wNormal, 1.1 ) ).rgb;`

Comment: I have found that the error will happen after GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + 1. The first face has no problems.

Comment: I suspect that you might be doing something in code that is not shown to cause this. For example, unbinding the FBO, deleting the FBO, or deleting the cube map texture. Getting a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` from `glFramebufferTexture2D()` with your argument means that either no FBO is bound, or that `m_cubeMap[0]` is not a valid cube map texture anymore.

Comment: I think it is a shader problem? Please look at update.